# Why differential flatness is called "flat"?

Tags: control

A system is differentially flat if the state and control input can be written as functions of the flat outputs and their time derivatives.

In other words, if a system is differentially flat, we can represent the state of the system and control signal as:
$$x = x(y, \dot y, \ddot y, ... , y^{(p)})$$
$$u = u(y, \dot y, \ddot y, ... , y^{(q)})$$

It's really a nice property of the system. But I don't quite get the name of this property. Why it is called differential "flatness". What does it have to do with "flat"?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but [(Fliess 1995)](http://pierre.rouchon.chez-alice.fr/publications/PR1995/IJC95.pdf) says: "the terminology flat is due to the fact that y plays a somehow analogous role to the flat coordinates in a differential geometric approach to the Frobenius theorem" (p. 3). Also, there is a [geometric definition of "flat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_(geometry)) which might be coming into play.